# AngularJs - Filtrar checkbox do ng-repeat

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, html5, dom

Tendo em mente que tenho um ng-repeat, como faço para pegar somente os itens que eu marquei no checkbox?

Comment: Poderia inserir o que esteve tentando por favor? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue exemplo, veja se lhe atende.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.itens = [
      {id: 1,name: "nome 1"}, 
      {id: 2,name: "nome 2"}, 
      {id: 3,name: "nome 3"}
    ];
    $scope.marcados = function() {
      var checkedItems = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.itens, function(item, arrayIndex) {
        if (item.id === true) {
          checkedItems.push(item)
        }

      })
      return checkedItems
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in itens">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.id">{{item.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{itens}}
  <br><br>
  marcados: {{marcados()}}
</div>
```